# object has no attribute pose bone

Tags: rigging, rigid-body-simulation, auto-rig-pro

hey all so I m Trying to actually rig a car with the addon rig a car, I watched many videos on youtube and I FIGURED it out , after I parent the wheels , named them etc , When I try to generate it there is an error , "posebone"Object Has no Atrribute Pose Bone , What Am I missing here?  thanks in advance [image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zRfd6kXsUqVkoo54sCxcdEFCf-ERL35B/view?usp=sharing

blend file

Answer (score 2):

Blender 4.0 introduces Bone Collections which replaces Bone Groups. The add-on needs to be updated to account for that change. Another option is to use this add-on with an older Blender version.